# Haskell flow and catMaybes

Tags: haskell

I am trying to fix the issue with https://github.com/dzhus/flickr-takeaway-processor/blob/master/src/Main.hs code here. I have spent 3 days learning (%0.1 of) Haskell. Which seem to be a nice language but still not there :(

So here comes my question;

```
  sidecars <- catMaybes <$> forConcurrentlyN maxThreads jsons parseSidecar
```

This line does not make sense, from what I understand it `fmaps` `jsons` and `parseSidecar` however it matches nothing in the end.

Also, the `parseSidecar` is just return the decoded `string`, right?

```
parseSidecar :: MonadIO m => FilePath -> m (Maybe PhotoMeta)
parseSidecar jf = do
  res <- liftIO $ P.readFile $ encodeString jf
  return $ decode $ fromStrict res
```

I could not find a way to use a debug where I used to use with .Net or PHP :( And it took me some time to understand the shorthand structure.

Comment: It `fmap`s the `forConcurrentlyN maxThreads jsons parseSidecar`, so likely that means it will concurrently perform `parseSidecar` on the elements of `jsons`, and that will return something of type `m [Maybe a]`, and by fmapping, we get a `m [a]`, where we thus only takes the ones wrapped i a `Just`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to dump operation?  I manage to print `json`s and its just paths like `photo_6116269424.json` and `parseSidecar` returns the string contents of each json file:) It never gets a `Just`, when I print `sidecar` I get `[]` That's why I've been focusing on this piece to sort the issue.

Comment: you can work with [**`traceShow`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:traceShow) for debugging purposes.

Comment: Everything here is in `IO` already, you can just use `print` (or `liftIO print` when dealing with `MonadIO m => m`). Don't mess with `traceShow`, you'll just confuse yourself if you don't already have a good mental model of lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Since your post, the library has been updated to use `Either` instead of `Maybe`. I will work with the [original version](https://github.com/dzhus/flickr-takeaway-processor/blob/05029d3391015b64ac07a211291f56d0afa21748/src/Main.hs) that you have seen.

In the original source you had this code:

```hs
sidecars <- catMaybes <$> pooledForConcurrentlyN maxThreads jsons parseSidecar
```

The `<$>` operator is an infix version of `fmap`, so this is equivalent to:

```hs
sidecars <- fmap catMaybes (pooledForConcurrentlyN maxThreads jsons parseSidecar)
```

`fmap` on a monadic action applies a pure function to the result of the action.  [`pooledForConcurrentlyN`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio-0.2.14/docs/UnliftIO-Async.html#v:pooledForConcurrentlyN) is a parallel version of `forM`, so this line is functionally equivalent to:

```hs
maybeSidecars :: [Maybe PhotoMeta] <- forM jsons parseSidecar
let sidecars :: [PhotoMeta] = catMaybes maybeSidecars
```

I have added type annotations to the variables for clarity. You can think of `forM` as similar to a `for` statement.

So the line quoted performs the following actions:

- For every `FilePath` in `jsons`, perform the `parseSidecar` action in parallel using max `maxThreads` threads, yielding a `[Maybe Photometa]` of the results of each parse.
- join all the successful (`Just`) results into a `[Photometa]`. If no parses where successful (all yielded `Nothing`), an empty list will result.

`PhotoMeta` is defined on [line 76](https://github.com/dzhus/flickr-takeaway-processor/blob/05029d3391015b64ac07a211291f56d0afa21748/src/Main.hs#L76) as a datatype containing various metadata, extracted from the JSON. This derives `show`, so running `liftIO (print pm)` on a `PhotoMeta` `pm`, either in your code or at the GHCi prompt, will print a readable representation of the structure for debugging.

The reasonm for the `<$>` idiom is as follows: you really want to write something like

```hs
catMaybes (forM jsons parseSidecar)
```

like you would in an imperative language. Problem is, the result of `forM/pooledForConcurrentlyN`, before execution in the Monad, is `IO [Maybe PhotoMeta]`, not `[Maybe PhotoMeta]` that `catMaybes` expects. `fmap` performs the neccesary conversion (it wraps the function around the action so it is applied when the action is executed). The infix `<$>` makes this code as similar as possible to the straightforward version.

Haskell is a carefully designed language with several objectives that are different from conventional languages, and therefore does many things quite differently from other languages you may be used to. As you increase your experience and understanding of Haskell, although you still might not agree with those design decisions, you will come to understand the reasoning behind them.

Happy Haskelling!